# Jaxb outputting invalid Xml when data contains xmlns=""

Tags: xml-namespaces, jaxb2

I have jax-ws service implemented using cxf with jaxb binding. It receives xml from another downstream service, Unmarshals this xml in to a POJO and saves it to persistent caching store. Future requests are served from this persistent store. Some times the xml received from downstream service contains xmlns="". The service is able to unmarshal the xml from the persistent caching store but when it marshals back the response to the client, the xml is not well formed.
Here is the xml i.e. received from downstream service. Notice the PolicyID element with xmlns="".

```
<message:RetrieveOrderResponse
xmlns:common="urn:xyz:om:common:defn:v1" xmlns:message="urn:xyz:om:order:messages:v1"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<common:MessageInfo CreateDateTime="2015-04-17T13:13:36.819-07:00"
    MessageGUID="d8ad2956-ff69-45ff-9d57-c30dc50569a1" TransactionGUID="a772169a-b138-40e7-8d16-ca86b68d38b8">
    <common:DebugTraceBoolean>true</common:DebugTraceBoolean>
</common:MessageInfo>
<common:MessageStatus>
    <common:Status>Success</common:Status>
</common:MessageStatus>
<common:OrderList>
    <common:Order>
        <common:OrderLineList>
            <common:OrderLine>
                <common:OrderLineData namespace="urn:xyz:e3:data:abc:types:v1"
                    type="xyzProduct">
                    <ns2:xyzProduct xmlns:datatype="urn:xyz:om:supply:datatype:defn:v1"
                        xmlns:finance="urn:xyz:e3:data:financetypes:defn:v4"
                        xmlns:internal="urn:xyz:cc:es:order:internal" xmlns:min="xalan://org.jaxen.function.MinDateTimeFunction"
                        xmlns:ns2="urn:xyz:e3:data:abc:types:v1" xmlns:ns3="urn:xyz:e3:data:basetypes:defn:v4"
                        xmlns:ns4="urn:xyz:e3:data:financetypes:defn:v4" xmlns:ns5="urn:xyz:e3:data:timetypes:defn:v4"
                        xmlns:ns6="urn:xyz:e3:data:messagetypes:defn:v5" xmlns:ns7="urn:xyz:e3:data:placetypes:defn:v4"
                        xmlns:ns8="urn:xyz:om:supply:messages:defn:v1">
                        <PolicyID xmlns="" /> 
                        <ns2:abcProduct>
                            <ns2:DiningSeatingInformation>
                                <BookingStatusCode xsi:nil="true" />
                                <DinSeatingCode xsi:nil="true" />
                            </ns2:DiningSeatingInformation>
                        </ns2:abcProduct>
                    </ns2:xyzProduct>
                </common:OrderLineData>
            </common:OrderLine>
        </common:OrderLineList>
    </common:Order>
</common:OrderList>
```

This xml is subjected to the following steps.

1. unmarshal in to a POJO
2. marshal the POJO back to xml
3. unmarshal the xml from step 2 back to POJO
4. marshal the POJO from step 3 to xml
   The resulting xml from step 4 is not well formed. In the example below, the start tag for OrderLineData is bound to valid namespace prefix but the end tag is unbound. If I remove the xmlns="" from the xml then step4 outputs well formed xml. Here is the badly-formed xml.

   true


       Success

Any hints on how to handle such xml?

Comment: For some reason, I could not get the bad xml to show up in my questions. Uploading to s3. Hope it is visible to everybody. https://s3.amazonaws.com/uploads.hipchat.com/28219/710237/b5vCWEeGmEYIOBF/xmlfile2.out.xml

Answer (score 0):

Are you using classes generated by some XSD ? if yes make sure you have package-info.java class in the generated package. This class is responsible for namespace handling and it is used during marshal/ unmarshal process.